# How to extract (slice) fixed sized 2D arrays from a formatted file using Python?

Tags: python

I have a file that contains a set of multiple 2D arrays stacked above each other and separated by strings. This file is generated from another software which I don't have control of its output.
I would like to separate these sets into separate files using a "for" or "while" loop.

i.e.,

1. the loop will look where the string characters begin (`"x"   "y"`),
2. Copy the data until the next string begins (2nd string not included in the copy)
3. create a new file and save the copied data.
4. proceed this way until all data is copied out

Here is an example of the data, this contains only 2 sets, which can be done manually, but I have a file that contains 10s of sets:

```
"x" "y"
1e+06   28.1647
1.77828e+06 28.1647
3.16228e+06 28.1646
5.62341e+06 28.1646
1e+07   28.1645
1.77828e+07 28.1641
3.16228e+07 28.1629
5.62341e+07 28.1591
1e+08   28.1471
1.77828e+08 28.1095
3.16228e+08 27.9924
5.62341e+08 27.6412
1e+09   26.6846
1.77828e+09 24.5621
3.16228e+09 21.0562
5.62341e+09 16.5839
1e+10   11.599
1.77828e+10 6.18774
3.16228e+10 0.10613
5.62341e+10 -6.99352
1e+11   -15.4214
1.77828e+11 -25.7501
3.16228e+11 -40.0745
5.62341e+11 -58.1688
1e+12   -66.9569

"x" "y"
1e+06   28.1784
1.77828e+06 28.1784
3.16228e+06 28.1784
5.62341e+06 28.1783
1e+07   28.1782
1.77828e+07 28.1778
3.16228e+07 28.1767
5.62341e+07 28.173
1e+08   28.1614
1.77828e+08 28.1249
3.16228e+08 28.0114
5.62341e+08 27.6705
1e+09   26.738
1.77828e+09 24.6535
3.16228e+09 21.1808
5.62341e+09 16.7247
1e+10   11.7433
1.77828e+10 6.3266
3.16228e+10 0.230876
5.62341e+10 -6.88885
1e+11   -15.3386
1.77828e+11 -25.689
3.16228e+11 -40.0328
5.62341e+11 -58.2147
1e+12   -67.1267
```

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to write code that implements the algorithm you have described?

Comment: I couldn't implement it, I couldn't loop through the data and update what to copy.